# Ubuntu SDK, QML: how do I create a vertical slider?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I am trying to create a vertical slider: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/current/Ubuntu.Components.Slider/

How can I do that?
Just rotating it doesn't seem like a good idea, it messes up anchors and such.